# Better way to write multiple replaces in Python

Tags: python, regex

So i currently have the following replaces in Python

```
f = f.replace("</ ", "</")
f = f.replace("<? Xml", "<?xml")
f = f.replace("<String", "<string")
f = f.replace("</String", "</string")
f = f.replace("<Resources", "<resources")
f = f.replace("</Resources", "</resources")
```

This is because there is some malformed parts in my XML file.

Is there a better, more clean way to write this part?

Comment: You might just let the lenient parser do the job. Try parsing the XML as is with `BeautifulSoup` and "xml" features.

Comment: As `str.replace` returns the new string you can chain the statements, i.e. `f = f.replace(...).replace (...)`. Apart from that the code is explicit which is positive. For only a few cases as in your scenario it's not worth trying to come up with some more generic rules in order to merge multiple cases into one while giving up the explicit intention of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of tuples `(a, b)` where you want to replace `a` with `b`

```
def rep_many(s, l):
    for a, b in l:
        s = s.replace(a, b)
    return s
```